# How can i dynamically add values to my chart from a javascript function via <li> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the javascript function in this section that does some evaluation.

**Javascript**

```
function getValue($value ){
    if($value<100) {
        return $value;
    } else if ($value>100 && $value<1000) {
        return ($value/1000*100);
    }else if($value>1000 && $value<10000){
        return ($value/10000*100);
    }else if($value>10000 && $value<100000){
        return ($value/100000*100);
    }
}
```

The chart gets drawn from here. When I call the getValue() function from the li tag as shown below, it does not draw the value as other bars get drawn.

```
<div class="bar-stats">
    <ul class="progress-stat-bar clearfix">
        <li data-percent="getValue(600);" ><span class="progress-stat-percent pink"></span</li>
        <li data-percent="400"><span class="progress-stat-percent"></span></li>
        <li data-percent="700"><span class="progress-stat-percent yellow-b"></span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bar-legend">
        <li><span class="bar-legend-pointer pink"></span> Total Sales</li>
        <li><span class="bar-legend-pointer green"></span> Total Earnings</li>
        <li><span class="bar-legend-pointer yellow-b"></span> Total Profit</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="daily-sales-info">
        <span class="sales-count">700<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> </span> 
        <span class="sales-label">Total Profit</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like :

in html :

```
<li id="li1" >...</li>
```

end after the at the `getValue`function in the js file, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) :

```
$("#li1").css("data-percent" : getValue(600)
```

for each style variable you want to change

Comment: its bringing an error on the document.getElementById("li1").style.data-percent = getValue(600);

Comment: do you have imported jQuery ? (That is a very populare library for js)

Comment: You must add in the head section of the html : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I still get an error with a message "invalid assignment left hand side"

Comment: My bad try this in the js instead `$("#li1").css("data-percent" : getValue(600)) `

Comment: `data-percent` is not a css propperty. Use `$("#li1").attr("data-percent", getValue(600))`, and don't forget the `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 0):

for html:

```
<li id="test"></li>
```

In javascript:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = getvalue(your_value);
```

Comment: but that looks like it wont solve the issue coz i need to assign a value to data-percent

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<li id="listItem1" >...</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("listItem1").setAttribute("data-percent", getvalue(your_value));
```